# Show ONLY notification dot on app icon WITHOUT notificatioN

Tags: android, android-notifications

Does there exists any mechanism in Android where ONLY notification dot gets displayed without any notification item ?

I just want to show notification dot on app icon to notify user about updates within the app.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Yes. check out something called as **Notification Badge** on Google

Comment: @UmangBurman Could not get anything on Google. Looks like my question is not clear to you.

Comment: Did you see this? https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/badges

Comment: Which API level are you targeting?  That dot didn't come around until API 26, before that you had to use a [3rd party lib](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger) to use the launcher to add badge.

Comment: @UmangBurman Yes i went through this tutorial and sample codes. It triggers a notification item in status bar. I do not want notification item only dot on app icon. Hope my question is much clear to you now.

Comment: @JamesPoag I am targeting Android O and higher for my requirements.

Comment: @Shabbir Panjesha you got anything on this?

Comment: Has anyone have a solution to this problem?